# Measure label cardinality in Prometheus?

Tags: prometheus

I want to check how cardinality of one label has changed over time.

I tried with simplest:

```
count by (problematic_label)(server_request_duration_ms_bucket)
```

but for 12h query range it takes 60s to get a response.

Is there a faster way to track label cardinality or should I create recording rule based on "count by" query...?

Comment: I don't think you calculating cardinality of the label correctly (or at least what I'd call cardinality of label). My understanding of cardinality is a number of unique values of a label itself, and for this you'd need query like `sum(group by(problematic_label)(server_request_duration_ms_bucket))`.